# Mangled tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

While trying to get scipy installed under OS X, I temporarily installed Anaconda, and wound up having two versions of Tk.  To resolve the complaints this generated, I moved the original version of some Tk or tkinter file (like _tkinter.so or some such, and nested under /System or maybe /Library) to a temporary location.  I ultimately uninstalled Anaconda, and now when I try to, for instance, import the turtle library, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import Tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

Can someone tell me how to recover/reinstall the original version of Tk that was installed with OS X?

Comment: What I do on my mac is install ActivePython from ActiveState, and forget about using the system version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Got to your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get python-tk
```

And if this doesn't work you could just remove the package anaconda like:

```
apt-get remove [anaconda]
```

And then reinstall Tkinter like:

```
sudo apt-get python-tk
```